# Xposed goes into bootloop -Can I still make Xposed work somehow? (Device Pipo X8)

Tags: boot-loop, xposed-framework

I have installed Xposed onto my Android device and it doesn't work and goes into a bootloop. If I disable Xposed I get out of the bootloop so no problem there, except that I really need for Xposed to work. Is there something I can try to make it work? I tried `rm -r /data/dalvik-cache` but it doesn't help. What else can I do?

The device is a Pipo X8 media center with Android 4.4.4 and Windows dual boot, however I only use Android. For Kernel-version it says:

> 3.10.20-00003-g7240abc-dirty ibuilder@Exdroid #26 Thu Jul 23 17:21:56 CST 2015

Comment: It would really help, if you add specific details about your phone, software, firmware, Xposed version etc.

Comment: You say you are under 4.4.4 are you using dalvik or art ?

Comment: I don't have the option to select runtime in developer options. How can I know/choose dalvik or art?

Comment: If there's no option, it will be Dalvik. ART was still experimental with Kitkat. Something else to check: How did you install Xposed? Did you use the installer? If not, did you pick the correct version (AFAIK there are 3 different versions: one for up to Kitkat, one for Lollipop, one for M)?

Comment: Did you use the installer here: http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer?

Comment: Yes I used adb to install **de.robv.android.xposed.installer_v32_de4f0d.apk** (stable for Android 4.0.3 or later.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get Xposed Framework 2.6.1 working on Pipo X8. I have described the steps necessary in my reply #15 on XDA forum. Please have a look:
[Xposed for Pipo X8 -infinite bootloop](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-pipo-x8-infinite-bootloop-t3271400/post64867203#post64867203)